# I want to change material ui swith color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using a material UI switch I want to change the switch color according to my choice but I tried some ways but not getting the proper result

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  
  toggle: {
   '& .Mui-checked': {
      color: '#454545',
      transform:'translateX(25px) !important'
  },
  '& .MuiSwitch-track': {
      backgroundColor:'#000'
  }
},
}));
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: blue,
  },
});

<Switch
  color="primary"
  size="small"
  checked={showUserListTable}
  onChange={(event) => {
  setShowUserListTable(event.target.checked);
                   
 }}
/>
```

Comment: how you want and what you get. please provide those images, so we have a better understanding of them.

Comment: see I add one new image i need like this not like red color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want results like that?

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-bouman-19xup?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

import switch and makeStyles

```
import { Switch, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
```

use the following code to change the color

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  switch: {
"& .Mui-checked": {
  color: "#00e68a"
},
"& .MuiSwitch-track": {
  backgroundColor: "#00e68a !important"
}
}
});
```

and then do this

```
export default function App() {
const classes = useStyles();
const [showUserListTable, setShowUserListTable] = useState(false);
```